# How do I swap accuracy with another performance metric from the score() function after fitting the ML model in Pipeline with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

Here is a part of my code:

```
def ml_pipeline(self):
    if self.control_panel['ml_pipeline_switch']:
        self.model = make_pipeline(self.preprocessor, self.control_panel['ml_algo'][1])
        self.model.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)

def ml_pipeline_result(self, show_control_panel_switch=True): 
    if self.control_panel['ml_pipeline_switch']:
        print('Model score (training set): %.3f' % self.model.score(self.X_train, self.y_train))
        print('Model score (test set): %.3f' % self.model.score(self.X_test, self.y_test))
```

The `score()` seems to be producing accuracy. How can I swap accuracy with another performance metrics such as `F1-macro` or `recall-macro`? I couldn't find anything in the [document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is no, unless you hack your way through and redefine/overwrite the `scikit-learn` functions.

When you are using `pipe.score()`, it calls the score method from the classifier that is in the end of the pipeline.

Now, what is happening under the hood is that all classifiers in `scikit-learn` are based on the `ClassifierMixin` class, for which `.score()` is defined through `accuracy_score`, and this is hard-coded (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f69242646d239d89a5713982946b8ffcf9d9/sklearn/base.py#L328)).